# PL/SQL NVL and OracleParameter doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, plsql

I'm trying out some basic stuff, found that the OracleParameter doesn't seem to bind as it should in C#

When using the `OracleParameter` in my example `CaseLocalId` the parameter doesn't seem to bind. The query runs but won't return any rows. But when using the secondary option `and c.case_local_id like nvl('{CaseLocalId}','%')` things works as supposed.

Any ideas?

```
string CaseLocalId = null;

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asd"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand
    {
        Connection = conn,
        Parameters =
        {
            // CaseLocalId
            new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "CaseLocalId",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                IsNullable = true,
                Value = CaseLocalId,
            }
        },
        CommandText = $@"
                select c.case_local_id, c.title, c.description
                from asd.CC_CASE_TASK t, asd.CC_CASE c
                where c.case_local_id = t.case_local_id(+)
                and c.case_local_id like nvl(':CaseLocalId','%') -- doesn't work
                -- and c.case_local_id like nvl('{CaseLocalId}','%') -- this works
                ",
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,                        
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't see any PL/SQL. Maybe that should be Oracle SQL (see [`plsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) tag info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`':CaseLocalId'` is the **literal** `':CaseLocalId'` - i.e. a string made up of a colon, a C, an a, etc... not the value of the parameter; you probably mean:

```
 nvl(:CaseLocalId,'%')
```

`'{CaseLocalId}'` does string injection **in the C#** before it gets near the ADO.NET layer, and does not use a parameter; it is a SQL injection hole - avoid.

As a general rule: SQL-related literals in C# should **never** have a `$` prefix, but the `@` prefix is normal, healthy and fine.

Note that you may also need to add:

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, needed to remove the `'` and add the `BindByName`